# Detecting Gibbs Sampler convergence with Raftery and Lewis Diagnostic

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, monte-carlo, convergence, gibbs

> Hi!
>
> I'm trying to understand and implement the Raftery and Lewis Diagnostic for detecting the number of iterations required for a gibbs sampler but cant seem to understand the formula.
>
> Can someone help me understand the formula through an intuitive example maybe?
>
> Research Paper available at: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.6474&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The Raftery and Lewis' diagnostic is not particularly trustworthy, so I would not advise using it.

Comment: Okay, then any other diagnostics which i can use to detect the convergence of the Gibbs Sampler which is easy to understand and implement?